# Running apache without port forwarding?

Tags: apache-2.2, port-forwarding

I am running a local server, and I want it to be accessible online, however, all ports appear to be closed, and I do not have access to set up port-forwarding.  Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Yes, talk to your system administrator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not to my knowledge. Your other option is to put it in the DMZ (if the router has the function available), but my guess is that you don't have access to the router in any way, shape, or form if you can't port forward.

Comment: This looks like the correct answer, however the question is a tad vague.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ssh access from the webserver to a machine outside your firewall, you can setup a port forwarding with it .. If the remote machine's sshd allows that.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a tunnel or VPN connection from a host that does have connectivity.